# Regulation changes for money market IRAs limiting transfers or rollovers?

Tags: united-states, ira, regulation, money-market

I have a money market IRA at Chase, and I recently received a letter about upcoming policy changes related to this kind of account. It noted that the changes were in response to new regulations, but didn't elaborate further on that point.

The only change I really care about is that I'll soon no longer to be able to do transfers or rollovers from other retirement accounts. My question is this: is it a regulatory requirement that Chase implement this policy, and thus it will be the same at every other bank? Or is this something Chase is choosing to change, and it's only tangentially (or not at all) related to regulations?

Comment: You give no hint what changes are being made. How can anyone answer this?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer "The only change I really care about is that I'll soon no longer to be able to do transfers or rollovers from other retirement accounts."

Comment: Sorry, I saw that. Was that an explicit new rule or a side effect? This sounds bizarre, a rule that doesn't permit more money to come into account? Your sure you read this correctly?

Comment: It was one of the changes listed. I can still make contributions in person or by setting up automatic transfers from a checking account, but that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that I can't find anything on Chase's web site referencing a "Money Market IRA" I suspect that this is a type of account that they aren't actively supporting anymore, but aren't forcing you to cash it in.  I would call Chase to find out for sure, however.

That said, a money market is not a good investment if you are looking for any kind of growth.  They are basically a savings account that pay (currently) a small amount of interest.  You can get much better return from other low-risk investments.  You can rebalance periodically if you want to keep a certain amount of "cash" available.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, unfortunately. I'm aware of the investment limitations of this kind of account; I only opened it because I had a small amount of funds in a 401(a) that was going to force me to cash out.

Comment: The answer to your question is "ask Chase".  The rest is commentary, I grant you, but I can't think of any other reason why they wouldn't let you contribute to that account. No regulatory reason, anyways.